# react native rn-fetch-blob cannot read storage of android 10

Tags: android, react-native, android-10.0, android-internal-storage, rn-fetch-blob

```
`const dirs_read = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.SDCardDir + '/Whatsapp/Media/.Statuses';`
```

The above code is working properly on android 9 and lower but, can not read the status of android 10.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is in [privacy settings](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes), according to `SDCardDir` in path you don't access internal but extrernal storage where you need to add `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, and `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions. You can't access folder of another apps in internal storage at all ([see more](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage)).

Comment: The issue was with android 10 scope storage.